Spotfire: Get information from other row based on same ID
I have the below table and I want to get the Time that ID match with PreviousID in Spotfire.



ID
Time
POKey
PreviousID




6
0:59
A
6


7
1:00
A
6


9
1:02
A
6


13
1:06
A
9


14
1:07
A
9


15
1:08
A
9



The outcome should be as below:



ID
Time
POKey
PreviousID
PreviousTime




6
0:59
A
6
0:59


7
1:00
A
6
0:59


9
1:02
A
6
0:59


13
1:06
A
9
1:02


14
1:07
A
9
1:02


15
1:08
A
9
1:02



It should be pretty similar like the below query in SQL.
SELECT a.ID, a.Time, a.POKey, a.PreviousID, b.Time as PreviousTime
From Table a, Table b
WHERE a.PreviousID = b.ID
Can some one please help me out with this?
Thanks for your time and assistance!

This is a self join, so I would join the data back to itself.
You need to start from a copy of your data table, to avoid 'cyclic dependencies'. Select ='+' then from 'Linked copy to data table in analysis', select your data table. Save it as a new data table with a new name.
In the data canvas, choose 'Add columns' to this new data table, then select the original table, and customise the join so that:
POKey=POKey 

(if appropriate)
and
PreviousID=ID

Then carry forward only the [Time] column and rename it to PreviousTime.

Hello Gaia Thank you so much for your help. But could you please explain more on how to copy my data table and save it as new data table?

I did. To create a copy, select ='+' then from 'Linked copy to data table in analysis', select your data table. The + symbol is for adding data and appears as an icon on the top left of your dxp
